# Docker Chrome Memory Leak When Using --Disable-Dev-Shm-Usage

Tags: node.js, docker, selenium-webdriver, azure-container-instances

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71135033/nodejs-selenium-webdriver-for-linux-chrome-docker-image/71230999#71230999):

I am creating a NodeJS-based image that I install latest Chrome and Chromedriver on, then run a NodeJS-based cron job that uses Selenium Webdriver for testing on a one-minute interval.

This runs in an [Azure Container Instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/), which is the simplest way to run containers in Azure.

**My challenge is that Docker containers in ACI run with 64 MB of dev/shm by default, which causes Chrome failures due to the relatively low amount of memory. Chrome provides a `disable-dev-shm-usage` flag, but running that creates a memory leak that I can't seem to figure out how to prevent. How can I address this best for my container in ACI, please?**

**Azure Container Instance Container Memory Consumption**
[image]

**Dockerfile**

```sh
# 1) Build from this Dockerfile's directory:
#       docker build -t "<some tag>" -f Dockerfile .
# 2) Start the image (e.g. in Docker)
# 3) Observe that the button's value is printed.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 1) Use alpine-based NodeJS base image
FROM node:latest

# 2) Install latest stable Chrome
# https://gerg.dev/2021/06/making-chromedriver-and-chrome-versions-match-in-a-docker-image/
RUN echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | \
    tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | \
    apt-key add - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable libxss1

# 3) Install the Chromedriver version that corresponds to the installed major Chrome version
# https://blogs.sap.com/2020/12/01/ui5-testing-how-to-handle-chromedriver-update-in-docker-image/
RUN google-chrome --version | grep -oE "[0-9]{1,10}.[0-9]{1,10}.[0-9]{1,10}" > /tmp/chromebrowser-main-version.txt
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/latest_chromedriver_version.txt https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$(cat /tmp/chromebrowser-main-version.txt)
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(cat /tmp/latest_chromedriver_version.txt)/chromedriver_linux64.zip && rm -rf /opt/selenium/chromedriver && unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/selenium && rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && mv /opt/selenium/chromedriver /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$(cat /tmp/latest_chromedriver_version.txt) && chmod 755 /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$(cat /tmp/latest_chromedriver_version.txt) && ln -fs /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$(cat /tmp/latest_chromedriver_version.txt) /usr/bin/chromedriver

# 4) Set the variable for the container working directory, create and set the working directory
ARG WORK_DIRECTORY=/program
RUN mkdir -p $WORK_DIRECTORY
WORKDIR $WORK_DIRECTORY

# 5) Install npm packages (do this AFTER setting the working directory)
COPY package.json .
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm i
ENV NODE_ENV=development NODE_PATH=$WORK_DIRECTORY

# 6) Copy script to execute to working directory
COPY runtest.js .

EXPOSE 8080

# 7) Execute the script in NodeJS
CMD ["node", "runtest.js"]
```

**runtest.js**

```js
const { Builder, By } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Options } = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', async () => await main());

async function main() {
    let driver;

    try {
        //Browser Setup
        let options = new Options()
            .headless()                                 // run headless Chrome
            .excludeSwitches(['enable-logging'])        // disable 'DevTools listening on...'
            .addArguments([
                // no-sandbox is not an advised flag due to security but eliminates "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist" error
                'no-sandbox',
                // Docker containers run with 64 MB of dev/shm by default, which causes Chrome failures
                // Disabling dev/shm uses tmp, which solves the problem but appears to result in memory leaks
                'disable-dev-shm-usage'
            ]);
        
        driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(options).build();

        // Navigate to Google and get the "Google Search" button text.
        await driver.get('https://www.google.com');
        let btnText = await driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).getAttribute('value');
        log(`Google button text: ${btnText}`);
    } catch (e) {
        log(e);
    } finally {
        if (driver) {
            await driver.close();   // helps chromedriver shut down cleanly and delete the "scoped_dir" temp directories that eventually fill up the harddrive.
            await driver.quit();
            driver = null;
            log('   Closed and quit the driver, then set to null.');
        } else {
            log('   *** No driver to close and quit ***');
        }
    }
}

function log(msg) {
    console.log(`${new Date()}: ${msg}`);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Interestingly, it seems to stabilize once it reaches a certain consumption. The container is allocated 2 GB of memory. I don't see crashes in my app logs, so this seems functional overall.

[image]